# How to correctly layout wxWidgets/wxGTK items taking their size into account?

Tags: layout, responsive-design, wxwidgets

Everything inside my application is laid out using sizers with hard-coded border sizes. This makes it fit very nicely inside Windows with wxWidgets:

[image: My application in Windows.]

But when I started porting it to Linux with wxGTK, since GTK+3 elements can vary a lot in size, everything ends up being misaligned:

[image: My application in Linux.]

Is there a way to responsively layout items taking into account that controls can be in different sizes, and the discrepancies between points and pixels as units of measurement?

Answer (score 1):

You can't hard code any sizes to have a fighting chance of a layout working well on different platforms with different font sizes, DPI settings etc. If you're defining your layout in C++, use `wxSizerFlags::Border()`, `DoubleBorder()` etc methods. Also, align controls relatively to each other, e.g. using `Center()` for all the controls that should be in the same row (or use `wxFlexGridSizer`).